# Где скачать бесплатную версию(полную) Qt с++?

Tags: qt

Новичок в Qt. Открыл книгу Бланшет и Саммерфилда. На 2 примере из книги Qt Creator сообщает об отсутствии классов кнопок и виджетов, свою версию качал от сюда: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/

Comment: вариант 1 - в книге используется старый Qt 4, а Вы установили 5. Вариант 2 - не установили qt вообще.

Comment: какие пункты вы указали при установке? думается что вы не установили часть того что нужно

Comment: Ставил Qt Creator и Mingw 32-битную, можно ли и где добавить другие компоненты?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы упустили добавление компонент в `.pro` файле

```
QT       += core gui network
```

Возможно упустили добавление заголовочных файлов в .h файле проекта, например

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QAction>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QStringListModel>
```

Я последний раз ставил через

https://www.qt.io/download-open-source - последняя кнопка внизу <kbd>Download the Qt Online Installer</kbd>

Comment: при установке требует регистрацию Qt аккаунта и свои данные(город, имя... и тд) нужно ли всё это?

Comment: это для аналитики всякой, если есть кнопка пропустить - пропусти

Comment: кнопки пропустить не наблюдаю, просит подтвердить создание аккаунта через почту, и далее данные свои указать

Comment: ну подтверди) левой почты нет ?) да можно подтвердить и на основную почту.